# Can a stack machine be implemented with `std::stack`?

Tags: c++, stack-machine

I was reading up on stack machines today, and I started thinking whether it makes sense to implement it with `std::stack` in C++.

The issue with `std::stack` is that you can't access elements below the top of the stack without popping everything above the element of interest...

How would one implement it with `std::stack`?

I think you would have to use `std::deque` or `std::vector` or a custom data structure that allows you to access any element in the stack?

Comment: Yes, stack machine can be implemented with std::stack. The only reason to access elements below top is for some optimization purposes.

Comment: @freakish So I'm still a bit fuzzy on the details of stack machines, but isn't there some `jump` method where you have to jump to different indices below the top? and it may entail swapping out some instruction below the top? in which case it would be difficult to do with `std::stack`

Comment: Why would there be such weird `jump` instruction? And even if you want such instruction you can simply pop/push n times. Stack machines are turing complete, and thus can do everything any computer can do.

Comment: @h8n2: stack machines are named that because they work entirely on a stack. They (in theory) do not have any quirks that make them not work on a stack.

Comment: I'd agree with @freakish that in theory, the answer is "yes, you can implement a stack machine using only the interface provided by `std::stack`", but I'd add that you most likely wouldn't want to. Doing so would potentially add overhead in some very low-level primitives that could affect a lot that ran on that "machine", and you'd get little or nothing in return.

Comment: @freakish I think sometimes you need to jump to some instruction and execute that? And then after executing you should presumably remove it from the stack of instructions? that's my understanding at least

Comment: @h8n2 there's a misunderstanding. Instructions (in particular "jump to instruction" and its semantics) are not stored on stack. Stack is used to store local/temporary variables. Which is opposite to register machines, which keep local variables in fixed amount of registers. That's why I said that your "jump in stack" is weird, you don't need such thing.